# Sync ticks on multiple independent axis

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng, angular2-highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I am working on a diagram with 2 independent y-axes. The left one with temperature data and the right one with humidity data. I want to synchronize the ticks from the right axis with the ticks and grid lines from the left axis.

I have achieved synchronization with tickPixelInterval, but only with startOnTick and endOnTick enabled. But unfortunately this will scale the series down.

https://jsfiddle.net/chartman2000/wLrf9s7x/5/

```
    yAxis: [
    {
      // startOnTick: false,
        // endOnTick: false,
      gridLineWidth: 1,
      gridLineDashStyle: 'Dash',
      lineWidth: 1,
      lineColor: '#ea0016',
      labels: {
        format: '{value}°C',
      },
      tickPixelInterval: 300 / 5,
      min: 3,
      max: 25
    },
    {
        // startOnTick: false,
      // endOnTick: false,
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      lineWidth: 1,
      lineColor: '#008ecf',
      title: {
        rotation: -90,
      },
      labels: {
        format: '{value}%',
      },
      opposite: true,
      tickPixelInterval: 300 / 5,
      min: 23,
      max: 25.8,
    },
  ],
```

[Chart with false scaling but tick sync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiEwo.png)

Is there a solution to synchronize the ticks and get a correct scaling like in the chart in the second fiddle, where endOnTick and startOnTick are disabled?

https://jsfiddle.net/chartman2000/wLrf9s7x/

```
   yAxis: [
    {
      startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
      gridLineWidth: 1,
      gridLineDashStyle: 'Dash',
      lineWidth: 1,
      lineColor: '#ea0016',
      labels: {
        format: '{value}°C',
      },
      tickPixelInterval: 300 / 5,
      min: 3,
      max: 25
    },
    {
        startOnTick: false,
      endOnTick: false,
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      lineWidth: 1,
      lineColor: '#008ecf',
      title: {
        rotation: -90,
      },
      labels: {
        format: '{value}%',
      },
      opposite: true,
      tickPixelInterval: 300 / 5,
      min: 23,
      max: 25.8,
    },
  ],
```

[Chart with tick sync but false scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVS2F.png)

( violet, brown and orange series belongs to the left axis | blue series belongs to the right axis )

I've been looking for a solution for days. Hopefully you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually calculate and set `tickPositions`:

```
yAxis: [{
  ...,
  tickPositions: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25],
  min: 3,
  max: 25
}, {
  ...,
  tickPositions: [23.2545, 23.8911, 24.5274, 25.1637, 25.8],
  min: 23,
  max: 25.8,
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n9xhsqfb/1/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions

Comment: I have already played with the thought to position the ticks with the values. But I have not found a solution how to get the values to the exact same height. 

How did you come up with the values?

Comment: I calculated them on the basis on the first axis, from the proportions.